# How to use animation in Android 17 and below?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want use **animation** in my application and i write below codes. but this codes run on **android 18 and above**! but my application **minSDK** has **14**, this animations not show in android 17 and below! just show **api 18** and above!!!

My codes:

```
public void disableSearch() {
    searchEnabled = false;
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_out);
    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_in_right);
    out.setAnimationListener(this);
    searchIcon.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    inputContainer.startAnimation(out);
    searchIcon.startAnimation(in);

    if (listenerExists())
        onSearchActionListener.onSearchStateChanged(false);
    if (suggestionsVisible) animateLastRequests(getListHeight(false), 0);
}

/**
 * Shows search input and close arrow
 */
public void enableSearch() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    searchEnabled = true;
    Animation left_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_in_left);
    Animation left_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_out_left);
    left_in.setAnimationListener(this);
    inputContainer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    inputContainer.startAnimation(left_in);
    if (listenerExists()) {
        onSearchActionListener.onSearchStateChanged(true);
    }
    searchIcon.startAnimation(left_out);
}
```

**My animations :**

```
fadeinLeft.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <translate android:fromXDelta="70" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="150"/>
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="0" android:toAlpha="1" android:duration="200"/>
    </set>

    FadeOut.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <alpha
                android:duration="250"
                android:fromAlpha="1"
                android:toAlpha="0"/>
        </set>
```

How can i fix this and run this animations on android 17 and below ? Thanks all <3

Comment: Use `View.animate().` which is very easy. If you share anim xml code, i will explain how to change.

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB', can you send me full code? please

Comment: add your anim xml code, i will show how to do it

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB', please see my uodate post

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' can you help me my bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your **FadeOut.xml** View animation goes like below :

```
yourView.animate().alpha(0).start();
```

According to your **fadeinLeft.xml** View animation goes like below :

```
yourView.animate().alpha(1.0).x(0).start();
```

And in this animation, the from value which is in your anim xml should be set before you call the above animation lines.

**For example:** If you want to start alpha animation from 0 to 1 and your current view alpha is 1, then you should do `yourView.setAlpha(0);` before doing the animation `yourView.animate().alpha(1).start();`.

Comment: Can you edit my above animations code with you new codes? please

Answer (score 0):

Have to extended your java class to AppCompatActivity

Doing this will import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity which is same as the Activity; only it allows support to backward compatibility.

Happy coding.

Comment: I Use create class and in this class i extend RelativeLayout not activity!